# AllenBradley Compactlogix PLC Ethernet IP & C# Communication?

Tags: plc, scada

I have Compact Logix Ethernet/Ip PLC. I want to make small scada/hmi on my pc with C#. I can use visual studio 2017 windows forms. I will take some data from plc to pc and I will show on c# and changed some picture image. 
how can I do communication C# and Allen Bradley PLC via ethernet/IP. I need your helps, sample programs, libraries, support, advises.

Answer (score 1):

Look at AdvancedHMI. It is an HMI/SCADA Visual Studio toolkit with AB drivers. You can do most HMI stuff without writing code, but you can also use VB or C# for advanced tasks.

Comment: thank you for reply. Advanced HMI is company. I think, I can not use it on professional application in industry without pay. I did a scada in C# for siemens s7-1500. it is good. I think, same is possible for rockwell AB PLC. I dont use opc or any other interface between plc and pc. direct ethernet ip communication was used. I hope same thing is possible for AB.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [EEIP Library](http://www.eeip-library.de). They have a C# and Java library for Ethernet/IP communication. They even offer some videos on YouTube on how to use it. But be aware, that some of this free libraries have some rough edges or bugs with them. Personally, I would use Modbus or another PLC before using Ethernet/IP along with a PC.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open-source project called [libplctag](https://github.com/libplctag) which has a few .NET wrappers, some of which are on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/libplctag/, https://www.nuget.org/packages/PlcTag.Net/

Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors of the first wrapper.